# UWP binding an icommand in a usercontrol works with x:bind and fail using binding elementname

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, binding

I did a very simple repro for my case:

```
MyControl1.xaml.cs:

 public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public ICommand SendInputCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SendInputCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SendInputCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SendInputCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MyControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TestBindingSolution.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestBindingSolution"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400"
x:Name="mycontrol1">

<Grid>

    <Button Content="ttt" Command="{x:Bind SendInputCommand}" />

</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestBindingSolution.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestBindingSolution"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewmodels="using:TestBindingSolution.ViewModels" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
x:Name="MyPage"
Loaded="Page_Loaded">
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>        
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button  Content="ssss" Command="{Binding DataContext.SendInputCommand,ElementName=MyPage}"/>
    <local:MyUserControl1 SendInputCommand="{x:Bind ViewModel.SendInputCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And finally MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TestBindingSolution.Custom;

namespace TestBindingSolution.ViewModels
{
    public  class MainPageViewModel : Observable
    {
        #region Commands 
        public RelayCommand SendInputCommand { get; }
        #endregion
        public MainPageViewModel() 
        {
            this.SendInputCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OnSendInputCommand,this.CanExecuteSendInputCommand);
            
        }

        private bool CanExecuteSendInputCommand(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void OnSendInputCommand(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as aspected using x:Bind but if i replace x:Bind ... with "{Binding DataContext.SendInputCommand, ElementName:MyPage}" i have an unhandled exception in InitializeComponent in the mainpage.xaml.cs
If you use the same bind the Command property of a button it works perfectly.
This is drive me crazy, where is my mistake?

UPDATE ----
below the classes i use for relaycommand and observable

```
public abstract class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual bool SetValue<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and here the RelayCommand

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        private Action<object> _commandAction;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecuteFunction;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> commandAction)
            : this(commandAction, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> commandAction, Func<object, bool> canExecuteFunction)
        {
            this._commandAction = commandAction;
            this._canExecuteFunction = canExecuteFunction;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool returnValue = true;

            if (this._canExecuteFunction != null)
            {
                returnValue = this._canExecuteFunction.Invoke(parameter);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this._commandAction != null)
            {
                this._commandAction.Invoke(parameter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't run your code successfully. Could you please share how your `Observable` is used? Which library is referenced?

Comment: Yes, for testing i used a couple of simple classes but you have the same issue using Community.toolkit.mvvm, As describe it works with a button and it works with a "normal" dependency properrty, i doesn't work with icommand in the custom control. i will add the classes in the post

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mistake when you are trying to register the `SendInputCommand` dependency property in the UserControl. You are registering the property name as **MyProperty** not **SendInputCommand**. So the binding failed to find the correct dependency property in your UserControl. That's why this behavior only happens for the UserControl.

Please change the code like this. Modify **MyProperty** to **SendInputCommand**.

```
  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SendInputCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SendInputCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Now your code should work correctly even using Binding.

Comment: You are right but is a mistake i did changing test again and again. The issue is still there

Comment: @Guru98 Please try to reproduce this issue in a new blank UWP project and share the project. Please remember to delete all the sensitive information and just keep the project as simple as possible.